# Plot grouped bar chart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am struggling to figure out how I can plot this. I did it in Excel, but not in R. I have tried in different ways, mainly with barplot, but I get either an error or nonsense. Please, can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Excel Bar Chart:

> [image: Excel Bar Chart]

Dataset:

> [image: Dataset]

Last trying code version:

I know I am making a mistake in barplot by putting the dataframe as it contains names rather than numbers, but I do not know how to put it correctly.

```
resp1 <- c(67, 58, 42, 47, 43, 48)
resp2 <- c(33,42,58,53,57,52)
question <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
dataframe <- data.frame(question,resp1, resp2)
barplot(dataframe, main="Answers",beside = TRUE,legend=TRUE, ylab="Rate %")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the **rAmCharts4** package:

```r
resp1 <- c(67, 58, 42, 47, 43, 48)
resp2 <- c(33, 42, 58, 53, 57, 52)
question <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
dat <- data.frame(question, resp1, resp2)

library(rAmCharts4)

amBarChart(
  data = dat,
  category = "question",
  values = c("resp1", "resp2"),
  valueNames = c("Response 1", "Response 2"),
  chartTitle = "My grouped bar chart",
  theme = "kelly",
)
```

[image]

You can even make it in 3D:

[image]

You can customize, e.g. add a "%" symbol to the tooltips:

```r
amBarChart(
  data = dat,
  category = "question",
  values = c("resp1", "resp2"),
  valueNames = c("Response 1", "Response 2"),
  chartTitle = "My grouped bar chart",
  theme = "kelly",
  tooltip =
    "[bold font-style:italic]{valueY.value.formatNumber('#p')}[/]"
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Solution using a bit of `dplyr` and base R..

```
resp1 <- c(67, 58, 42, 47, 43, 48)
resp2 <- c(33,42,58,53,57,52)
question <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
dataframe <- data.frame(question,resp1, resp2)

dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(question), names_to = "response", values_to = "value") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = question, values_from = value)

barplot(as.matrix(as.data.frame(dataframe2)[,-1]), col = c("red", "blue"), beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Solution using `ggplot` and `dplyr`

The only difference is that you need to pivot your dataset so that all the responses are in their own column and the values are in their own column.

You can read about `tidydata` in Hadley's R4DataScience book online.

See below:

```
library(tidyverse)

resp1 <- c(67, 58, 42, 47, 43, 48)
resp2 <- c(33,42,58,53,57,52)
question <- c("A","B","C","D","E","F")
dataframe <- data.frame(question,resp1, resp2)


dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(question), names_to = "response", values_to = "value")

   question response value
   <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
 1 A        resp1       67
 2 A        resp2       33
 3 B        resp1       58
 4 B        resp2       42
 5 C        resp1       42
 6 C        resp2       58
 7 D        resp1       47
 8 D        resp2       53
 9 E        resp1       43
10 E        resp2       57
11 F        resp1       48
12 F        resp2       52


dataframe %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = question, y = value, fill = response), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, a while quite complicated than the other proposed approach, but also useful for me. Many thanks for sharing.